# .net dictionary cache c#

Tags: c#, .net, caching, dictionary

Hi I want to make the code below run more efficiently using caching in .net. How do I get the contents on the dictionary cached so that when the `buttSubmit_Click()` is called the dictionary does not have to be redefined and cached data is used instead.

```
protected void buttSubmit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Dictionary<string, string> dict = new Dictionary<string, string>();
    dict.Add("rad1", "value1");
    dict.Add("rad2", "value2");
    dict.Add("rad3", "value3");
    dict.Add("rad4", "value4");

    string vValue;
    dict.TryGetValue(RadioButtonList.SelectedValue, out vValue);
    submitVote(vValue);
}
```

Comment: @CodeCaster that wouldn't really change anything...

Comment: @Marc wouldn't the statelessness of ASP.NET ask for a slightly different approach than a stateful WinForms form?

Comment: @CodeCaster The dictionary is re-created every button click as it is. The solution would be the same for both.. move it to class level.

Comment: If this is the size then you won't notice any speed up. When it goes up to `"rad2448877"` then it might be a good idea.  It's a UI, the slowest component is behind the keyboard.

Comment: @Simon OP says he _doesn't_ want to initialize the dictionary upon each button click, but cache it somewhere. _Where_ to do that depends on the layout of the rest of the application.

Comment: You could define the Dictonary in the Global.asax (http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/228879/Global-asax-in-ASP-NET)

Comment: I would change the lookup to: `if(dict.TryGetValue(RadioButtonList.SelectedValue, out vValue)) { submitVote(vValue); }` Because it returns a boolean `false` if the Key is not found.

Comment: WinForms or ASP.NET does matter for the solutions.

Comment: @CodeCaster not really - because if the data is as described, the *lookup data* is just as stateless in both scenarios, and should be treated as such.

Comment: `RadioButtonList` would suggest this is ASP.Net

Comment: +1 for inspiring some healthy debate with such a common question! :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, frankly if it is that simple I'd be *tempted* to use a `switch`, but - assuming that is a simplification, maybe make it a field (in this case I've made it `static`, but that is up to you):

```
private static readonly Dictionary<string, string> dict
      = new Dictionary<string, string> {
    {"rad1", "value1"},
    {"rad2", "value2"},
    {"rad3", "value3"},
    {"rad4", "value4"},
};

protected void buttSubmit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string value;
    if(dict.TryGetValue(RadioButtonList.SelectedValue, out value))
    {
        submitVote(value);
    }
}
```

Comment: I think I will go with this. But I still wanna know how go about with caching. Seems there is a lot of different ways of caching in .net but I can't pick one to use. Thanks to all.

Answer (score 2):

Declare and fill the Dictionary outside the method as a field.

Okay, I'll expand; as the static field is show in the other answer, here is the instance field:

```
protected Dictionary<string, string> dict = new Dictionary<string, string>();

public MyClass()
{
    dict.Add("rad1", "value1");
    dict.Add("rad2", "value2");
    dict.Add("rad3", "value3");
    dict.Add("rad4", "value4");
}

protected void buttSubmit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{    
    string vValue;
    dict.TryGetValue(RadioButtonList.SelectedValue, out vValue);
    submitVote(vValue);
}
```

Choice depends on the use case. If neither is good, consider a if/else block.

Comment: Seriously.. downvoters.. can you explain what is wrong for this user so they can fix their answer?

Comment: @SimonWhitehead indeed, the downvotes are confusing. I agree with the answer (but an example would make it a lot more usable)

Comment: When this is ASP.NET then a static field is a bad idea, an instance field won't work.

Comment: @HenkHolterman there's nothing wrong with a static field by itself - so long as you don't mutate it

Comment: @MarcGravell - agreed when it's totally immutable. But the answer here is still invalid for ASP.NET. It now works but it will recreate the cache on each request.

Answer (score 0):

To cache *constant* value simply avoid unnecessary initialization, something like:

```
Dictionary<string, string> dict = null;
protected void buttSubmit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if(dict == null)
    {
        dict = new Dictionary<string, string>();
        dict.Add("rad1", "value1");
        dict.Add("rad2", "value2");
        dict.Add("rad3", "value3");
        dict.Add("rad4", "value4");
    }

    string vValue;
    dict.TryGetValue(RadioButtonList.SelectedValue, out vValue);
    submitVote(vValue);
}
```

To cache *dynamic* data, you have to additionally provide a criteria to **reset** cache (making it `null` again) whenever data are changed and have to be re-cached.

Comment: Your use of `constant` and `dynamic` here are not in the "code keywords" sense - it would be a lot less confusing if you emphasized them instead, i.e. *constant* and *dynamic*

Answer (score 0):

Adding a global.asax to your project and adding your Dictionary to this as global static is a solution, too. This solution with global.asax has the (dis)advantage that it persistent for all users and requests - in the other solutions the Dictionary is created for every request newly. 
At first you have to create a global.asax in your web project (if not aleady in place):

[image]
[image: Global Asax 2]

Then you have to edit your global.asax.cs file and add your dict:

```
public class Global : System.Web.HttpApplication
{

    public static readonly Dictionary<string, string> TEST_DICT
              = new Dictionary<string, string> {
            {"rad1", "value1"},
            {"rad2", "value2"},
            {"rad3", "value3"},
            {"rad4", "value4"},
        };

}
```

If you want to access this dict simple call Global.TEST_DICT:

```
public partial class _Default : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Label_TESTDICT.Text = "";
        List<String> keys = Global.TEST_DICT.Keys.ToList();
        foreach (String key in keys)
        {
            Label_TESTDICT.Text += key + ":" + Global.TEST_DICT[key] + "<br>"; 
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I will also try this method. Thanks